# Flash CS6 read agenda from mobile or sim

Tags: android, iphone, actionscript-3, flash-cs6, contact-list

I want to develop an app for iOS and Android with Flash CS6 (Action Script 3).

I must read contacts from mobile agenda and SIM card, but I do not find any example or class reference.

Any example or link to start with?

Thank you.
J. Pablo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I discover long time ago that I need to use ANE (Adobe Navive Extensions), these are a few nice links:

http://mateuszmackowiak.wordpress.com/ (Look here for the github repo link)

http://extensionsforair.com/extensions/contact-editor/